# Visualizing a percentage of current view

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to display a users chat messages as a percentage of the current view/query.

I can get a visualization of the counts per user easily but is there a way to turn this into a percent of the all the selected users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it seems that what I am trying to do is not currently supported with the current elasticsearch (1.4.4) api and is part of the 2.0 roadmap.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/9876